# Telegram API throwing PeerFloodError after sending 50 messages at a sleep time of 120 seconds

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am sending messages from a python code, there seems a limit as after sending 50 messages I received
PeerFloodError Error: Too many requests (caused by SendMessageRequest)
Is there any way to move away this error as I have also increased the sleep time from 4 seconds to 120 seconds but the problem still persists or will I need to wait when I stop receiving this error (I  think I have to wait for 24 hours to again run my code)

Comment: Your account will receive a peer flood if you try spamming a lot of users in private.

Comment: So how should I message such that I do not encounter this error?

Comment: Limits are unknown and vary under many conditions. If you need to privately message thousands of users, you should use a bot account (and the users must be wiilling to start the bot first).

Comment: ok thanks Lonami, I think it has daily limit 50 so I will message daily 49 people and then I will not receive this error which also puts the restriction on my account, then will my account be safe If I somehow do not receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

there is a limit to send a message to users
see this: [https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#:~:text=When%20sending%20messages%20inside%20a,messages%20per%20second%20or%20so](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#:%7E:text=When%20sending%20messages%20inside%20a,messages%20per%20second%20or%20so).

Comment: Ok, but I am already giving sleep time of 120 sec, do I need to increase it more? If yes how much then?

Comment: there is limit of sending message a per second, it does not depend on sleep time, try not 20 messages not 50

Comment: If it does not depend on sleep time then they must have put a daily limit of 50, that is what I have observed